# Google map Authorization failure

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

I can not access my google play services though I have enabled the "Google Maps Android API v2" below the services. I followed the guide for Google Maps Android API v2 at this homepage: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.bustraffic"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <!--
     The following two permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>
    

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH-HHHHHHHHH7Sez7as" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

I corrected the speeling (bustrafic-->bustraffic) in the screenshoot of Simple API access but it didnt help.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

It works now I have just restarted eclipse.